# Within a Scrapy bot, I cannot increment a global variable (but can assign the same variable). Why?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I know that using global variables is not a good idea and I plan to do something different. But, while playing around I ran into a strange global variable issue within Scrapy. In pure python, I don't see this problem.

When I run this bot code:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["lib-web.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/michigan/"
    ]

    count = 0

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('p/text()').extract()

            global count;
            count += 1
            print count

            yield item
```

DmozItem:

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/Users/Admin/scpy_projs/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/dmoz_spider.py", line 22, in parse
    count += 1
NameError: global name 'count' is not defined
```

But if I simply change 'count += 1' to just 'count = 1', it runs fine.

What's going on here? Why can I not increment the variable?

Again, if I run similar code outside of a Scrapy context, in pure Python, it runs fine. Here's the code:

```
count = 0

def doIt():
        global count
        for i in range(0, 10):
            count +=1
doIt()
doIt()
print count
```

Resulting in:

```
Admin$ python count_test.py
20
```

Comment: Just a typo at global count; Remove that semicolumn from the var's name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count` is a [class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) in your example, so you should access it using `self.count`. It solves the error, but maybe what you really need is an [instance variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), because as a class variable, `count` is shared between all the instances of the class.

Assigning `count = 1` inside the `parse` method works because it creates a new **local variable** called `count`, which is different from the class variable `count`.

Your pure Python example works because you did not define a class, but a function instead, and the variable `count` you created there has global scope, which is accessible from the function scope.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll go and review the difference between class and instance variables.